# Internet Explorer 10 - Removed Flash element still visible?

Tags: flash, embed, internet-explorer-10

I'm using `iframes` to add `Youtube/Vimeo` videos on my website.

Those `iframes` are removed dynamically using `jQuery`'s `$().remove()`. While that works  on `Chrome/FF/Opera/Safari`, it behaves randomly on `IE10` where the embed flash element usually remains visible.

I don't know how to fix this issue on `IE10` (I've yet to try it on *real* IE9, but it fails in emulated `IE9` mode too )

The bug is quite easy to reproduce :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="remove">REMOVE</button>
    <iframe src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=64232781"></iframe>
    <script>$( "#remove" ).on( 'click', function(){ $( 'iframe' ).remove(); } );</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Funnily enough, it works just fine on IE7/8 browser mode.

Has anyone ever ran into this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but it was related to a PDF in an iframe. The issue was also only in version 10.0.9200.16540 of IE10 and not in previous versions.

According to [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/8ff26bbd-9471-4137-ac6a-ff34ee02ab74/) the reason would most probably be invalid markup.

What I know so far:

1. "a workaround is to set the src value of the parent iframe to an empty string" (according to the above question)
2. hide the iframe with `.hide()` before the `.remove()`

The second option might not be the most elegant if the iframe is not actully removed from the page, but would be the easiest if is just a rendering issue.

Ill update this answer if I discover anything else.

Comment: Setting the src to an empty string worked around a problem I had with the sound of the Flash continuing playing after I killed the iframe. Thanks.